Why use "long periods" instead of "a long period"?

Groundwater is the word used to describe water that saturates the ground, filling all the available spaces. By far the most abundant type of groundwater is meteoric water; this is the groundwater that circulates as part of the water cycle. Ordinary meteoric water is water that has soaked into the ground from the surface, from precipitation (rain and snow) and from lakes and streams. There it remains, sometimes for long periods, before emerging at the surface again. At first thought it seems incredible that there can be enough space in the “solid” ground underfoot to hold all this water.


Why do you think it should be "a long period"? Have you looked at other questions about singular vs plural?

Because I saw the word "it", I though it was a single example.

One could possibly argue that "it" (the water) isn't a singular whole, but consists of many parts. Some of those parts remain below the surface longer than others.

It (the water) remains underground for periods of varying length.

The author uses the plural because there are multiple occasions when groundwater emerges at the surface after being underground for a period of time. Some of these periods have been long ones.

There's no good reason.  "A long period" is probably better and certainly more precise, but "long periods" is also acceptable and idiomatic.
It does perhaps emphasize the extreme length of the period, as if the time were so long that it didn't fit into a single period.
